# How can I make adding a link to a doubly-linked list perform N/2 rather than O(N) (int index, element a) as parameters

Tags: list, linked-list, big-o

It seems that the only Big-Oh behavior possible for adding something to a linked list would be O(N) since you must traverse the entire list. However from what I hear the overall number of operations should be no more than N/2. Can someone please explain how this is possible, as I see it if you traverse from both ends of the linked list the overall behavior will still be O(N). What am I missing?

Comment: I was taught that this would be O(N), but perhaps if you move at once it maybe O(N/2). Numerical coefficients in algorithms are a rather tricky buisness because factors such as compiler/language/hardware can make an O(N) algorithm finish quicker then a O(N/2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are asking why will inserting an element at an arbitrary position in a doubly linked list of length N always take at most O(N/2), that could be because if you always maintain a separate pointer/reference to the middle element and a count of the total number of elements, you will only need to traverse at most half the list to insert at a given position.

For example, say you have a list of `[B, C, D, E, F, G, H]`, if you have a pointer to the `E` element and you know you have 7 items in your list. If you call `insert(0, A)` to insert element `A` at position `0`, then you'll know that if you traverse 3 links backwards you'll go from position 3 to position 0 (remember zero index is the first, so you go from `E`@3 -> `D`@2 -> `C`@1 -> `B`@0). From there you can insert element `A` before your 'current' element (`B`).

Note that people normally leave constant terms out of big-O analysis; O(n/2) and O(n) have the same performance characteristics as `n` increases.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about ordering, adding something to a linked list can be O(1) -- always add the new item at one end.

At a guess, the N/2 is based on an assumption that the list is sorted, so on average you only traverse half the list to find the correct insertion point.

If you want random access to the items, the real answer is simple: use something other than a linked list.